# Achieving the following scrolling header effect and the name of this effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've noticed the following header effect is being used by quite a few people now and I was wondering first of all if anyone can give me an insight into how this could be achieved, what the name of this effect is and also are there any good tutorials to learn?

The site is http://crane-brothers.com/ if you scroll once the css is updated, scroll again and the css is updated etc etc

Would be great if someone could give me some further insight into this technique.

Thanks and Happy New Year

Comment: What about disecting that page and learning how it works?

Comment: A possibly way to do is simply change the styles of some element (like background color) dinamically with JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling lazy and don't want to dissect anything, maybe this [jquery plugin](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) can help you.